# Calculus III Limits of Continuity - Nonexistence of limits.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

The question in place would have me figure out
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^4 - 2x^2}{y^4 + x^2}$$
What I have tried already:

I made $y = mx$, and I decided since m is an fixed constant, of which I have

decided to make 0. So, $y = 0x$, therefore $y = 0$.

So, I plug $y = mx$ into the function, and I get $(mx^4 - 2x^2)/(mx^4 + x^2)$, I then factored out $x^2$ from the top and the bottom, leaving me with $(mx^2-
2)/(mx^2 +1)$ and since $m = 0$, and that means our $x$ is automatically 0 as well

for $y = 0$. So, plugging that in, we are left with -2/1 of which the limit is $-2$.

Hey, that's right! (According to the book.)

Now, here is where my problem comes up, I do the same thing for $x = my , m = 0, x = 0$. So, that gives us $(y^4 -2my)/(y^4 +2(my)^2)$. Factor out $y^2$ because we

can, and we get $(y^2 -2m^2) / ( y^2 + m^2)$ and now I'm at an impasse.

You can't have 0 in the denominator, and I have a zero in the denominator.

I'm honestly not sure how to deal with this, please assist senpai. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a zero in the denominator, but $m=0$ and the expression reduces to $1$. Since the limit along $y=0$ was previously shown to be $-2$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: Why does the expression reduce to 1? Is that a theorem or a rule that I am missing?

Comment: @The_Senate you already set $m=0$. Then we have $(y^4-2×0^2)/(y^4+0^2)=y^4/y^4=1$.

Comment: Oooooooooo~ Got it, thank you. ^^